# Echo Cancellation and Noise Reduction for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: sound, microphone, noise, echo

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my ASUS TP200SA for a week now and after making a Skype call I have realized that the features that had with Windows are gone now. My laptop has a stereo microphone in terms of hardware yet the sound quality and lack of features are really bad with the stock drivers. Is it possible to install real Realtek drives to solve this problem? I am really bad at Linux, I hope someone can explain me in a basic way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and add the following lines to the end of the file and restart pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -k`

```
#Active Noise Removal
.ifexists module-echo-cancel.so
load-module module-echo-cancel aec_method=webrtc source_name=mic source_properties=device.description=MicHD
set-default-source "mic"
.endif
```