# how can I apply echo cancelation to audiofiles on ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-recording, audacity

it is possible to apply echo cancellation to microphones while they are recording, e.g. like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/892833/429927)

How can I apply the same filter to audio files that already exist?

If there was a ffmpeg filter for this, it would be applied like this:

```
ffmpeg -i FileWithEcho.mp3 -v $module-echo-cancel FileWithoutEcho.mp3
```

Comment: I am not aware of any echo cancellation filters in ffmpeg.

Comment: it wouldn't have to be ffmpeg any other software would be fine too